# Dashboard widgets run in background [10.9]

Tags: macos, dashboard-widget, dashboard

I have a webclip in my dashboard on mavericks with play.spotify.com in it and i like to control my music from there, but as soon as i go out of the dashboard the music stops.

I had this working a year back but that was on a other version of mac osx.

Is there a way to allow the dashboard to keep running even if im not looking at it.

Comment: Good question - since Safari is now designed to use no power when not visible to save battery the clear workaround would be to keep the clip visible somehow. Are you open to other methods to listen to spot if your does it have to be a web clip in dashboard?

Comment: I want to make the dashboard useful again and force me to look at it once in a while. i thought if i had my Spotify there it would be a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it there is a little 'i' icon in the right corner of the dashboard webclip (if you hover over it with you mouse).

By default there a check box "Only play audio in dashboard" unchecking this will keep on playing!